# SharePoint 2013 REST - Create list item with user field and lookup field

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm trying to add an  `SPListItem` to an `SPList` via `REST`, but have a problem with User or Group and Lookup (information already on this site).

```
function adddullitem() {

    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.OfficeReqListItem" },
        "Title": "123",
        "SomeUserorGroupField": "1",
        "SomeLookUpField": "10"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LISTNAME')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm trying to pass user's ID to User and group field and `SPListItem.ID` to LookUp field, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends whether User/Lookup field value is multiple or not, the following formats are used when specifying field value via SharePoint REST:

- Single User/Lookup value format: `FieldName: LookupIdVal`
- Mutiple User/Lookup value format: `FieldName: {"results": [LookupIdVal1,LookupIdVal2] }`

### How to set **multiple** lookup/user field value via SharePoint REST API

```
var listName = 'Tasks';

var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    "Title": 'New task',
    'AssignedToId': {"results": [12] }  //multi-valued User field value 
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

### How to set **single** lookup/user field value via SharePoint REST API

```
var listName = 'Tasks';

var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    "Title": 'New task',
    'AssignedToId': 12  //single-valued User field value 
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(taskProperties),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: This has helped me multiple times over the past week :)

Comment: i was try it but not work for me..can you please explain more. i am pass Id of user in json post but not work  its give 400 error

Comment: You have to add `Id` to the field name, e.g. `AssignedTo` becomes `AssignedToId`

Comment: It would be very helpful if the fact you have to add Id to the field name was present at the beginning of the answer

Answer (score 0):

yes add Id to column names it worked:

Columns :

Course_x0020_Id and Participant

```
    var courseId = GetQueryStringValues('ID');
    var currentUser  = GetCurrentUser();
    var todaysDate = GetTodaysDate();

    var itemToCreate = {'Category' : 'Register', 'Course_x0020_IdId' : courseId, 'ParticipantId' : currentUser, 'RegistrationDate' : todaysDate};
            var listURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items";
            srvcQuerySPList.createItem(listURL ,itemToCreate)
                .then(
                    function(data){

                        alert("Done");
                    },
                    function(data){
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                );
```

Comment: Needs the code for `GetCurrentUser()` to be posted.  Assuming it returns the current user's ID, and that the field is `Participant`, using `ParticipantId` to fill it is correct. Post could've benefited from that additional explanation.