# This list is currently being managed by Project Web App, and cannot be edited directly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, .net

I got this error when trying to update the Tasks:

> {"error":{"code":"-2130575223,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"This
>   list is currently being managed by Project Web App, and cannot be
>   edited directly"}}}

I've tried with Javascript and CSOM .NET. Is there something trouble in my Project Online? Or I just don't get the right procedure?

My previous question: [CRUD Tasks using Javascript via REST OData](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117990/crud-tasks-using-javascript-via-rest-odata)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this list is part of **Enterprise Project mode** then you can't edit it.

Task lists from Enterprise Projects are read-only and must be updated via the My Tasks link or via the schedule for the updates to be pushed down to the tasks list in the Project Workspace site.

But if this list belongs to  **Visibility Project (SharePoint Task List Project)** or **Task list synchronised with Project Pro** then tasks from these two can be modified by the user directly. [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/83a15e76-4afc-416f-b5a3-5925079353c0/error-this-list-is-currently-being-managed-by-project-web-app-and-cannot-be-edited-directly?forum=projserv2010setup)

Comment: I am not sure about it, but I got some clue in this : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163093(v=office.15).aspx). Get project -> check out project -> CRUD Task -> publish project. But I haven't found good tutorial for CRUD Task via javascript. The VS Intellisense for JS not good at all.